# EWS Item.Copy causes ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I want to copy items between mailboxes used EWS managed API. Here I've met strange situation.

When I try first to get destination folder and then copy item using its ID I get an error ErrorAccessDenied.

```
this.exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test1@test.local");
var folder = Folder.Bind(this.exchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
item.Copy(folder.Id);

This gets an error
```

If I create a FolderId object instance specifying well known folder name (Inbox) and mailbox name I get no problems.

```
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("test1@test.local"));
item.Copy(folderId);

This works
```

Is such behavior by design? Or I can use destination folder not just well known one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this behavior is by design. In the first example, the calling account (acct1) is impersonating acct2. I think that the request is being processed as acct2 trying to bind to the inbox of acct1 since the credentials of the call are associated with acct1. The context for calls are based on the identifiers which contain the SMTP address of the target mailbox.

Your second example explicitly identifies the mailbox that should be targeted. All subsequent identifiers accessed based on that folder identifier will have the context of test1@test.local.

I think you can change your first call to this to make it work:

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(this.exchangeService, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("test1@test.local")));
```

I know you are copying to a folder in to test1@test.local mailbox. Whose mailbox contains 'item'? I can't recall if it works to use impersonation to copy across mailboxes. I'm interested to know how it works for you.